# forEach parameter does not match Consumer functional interface parameters but code still compiles, why?

Tags: java, lambda, concurrency, return-type, executor

I am studying for the OCP exam and I noticed a following snippet of code, where the parameter to the forEach method invoked on a DoubleStream must match that of the DoubleConsumer functional interface, however the lambda does not match the required types, why does it still compile?

```
  DoubleStream.of(3.14159, 2.71828)
    .forEach(c -> service.submit(
      () -> System.out.println(10*c)
    ));
```

DoubleConsumer (accepts an argument of type Double and has a return type of void), however this forEach has a return type of `Future<?>` where ? denotes the return type of the Runnable lambda which is void, Future - this is not void. I am saying this because the return type of service.submit(...) is `Future<?>` it is not void, why does this code compile?

Comment: If the expected return type is `void` that means that no result is required. Java allows to return anything else here as well. It automatically just discards that. This is a "lossless" and safe conversion.

Comment: It's the same as a standalone statement `service.submit(...);` that doesn't assign the return value to a variable, the return value is *discarded*. If you can do the *discard* in a normal statement, why not when mapping a lambda expression to a functional method?

Comment: @Andreas No, I don't believe it is, the return type is not discarded: Consider the following lambda:

() -> 5.

The value 5 is considered as the return type, in the above case the return type of service.submit is considered the return type which is Future<Void>

Comment: A consumer just has to satisfy the contract of "do something with the stream element", which both `Function` and `Consumer` do.

Comment: @RamanSB Same as you cannot just write `5;`, since an expression is not a statement, `() -> 5` is not valid for a `void` functional method. However, `() -> String.valueOf(5)` is, even though it returns a value, since a method call with a return value can be used as a statement *and* in an expression. *Proof:* `Runnable x = () -> String.valueOf(5);` compiles and executes just fine. The return value from `valueOf()` is *discarded*, same as it would be as a standalone statement like `String.valueOf(5);`. The fact that method return values might be ignored is not new to lambdas.

Comment: @Andreas - Understood, thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really true that the return type of the lambda expression and the return type of the function type of the target functional interface type has to *exactly* match. The Java Language Specification specifies that `void` is a special case.

In [§15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), it says:

> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

We are in an invocation context here. `T` is `DoubleConsumer`. The ground target type derived from it is also `DoubleConsumer`, and its function type is a method that takes a `double` and returns `void`.

Let's see what does "congruent" mean:

> A lambda expression is congruent with a function type if all of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
> - If the lambda parameters are assumed to have the same types as the function type's parameter types, then:
>
>   - If the function type's result is `void`, the lambda body is either a statement expression ([§14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)) or a `void`-compatible block.

"assumed to have the same types as the function type's parameter types" basically means that you did not explicitly write out the type of `c`.

A statement expression is just an expression that can be made into a statement by adding a `;` at the end. Any method call is a statement expression. This is why the `submit` call compiles.

`5` is not a statement expression (but it is an expression), so `c -> 5` does not compile.

If you think about it, by saying that methods that returns *something* should not be assigned to functional interfaces whose function type has a void return type, you are saying that "functions that take a `A` and gives out a `B`" are not a kind of "consumers of `A`". However, they clearly *are* "consumers of `A`"! They take in an `A` after all. Whether or not something is a consumer of `A` doesn't depend on what they *produce*.

Hence, Java is designed to allow this.